# How to show output on terminal and save to a file at the same time?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome-terminal, linux-terminal

I am using:

```
user@unknown:~$ sudo command -option > log
```

to save the results of "command" to the file "log", but I'd like to also get the result on the terminal, is this possible?

I am using ubuntu 10.04 lts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Echoing output to file while seeing it in console in the same time](http://superuser.com/questions/694064/echoing-output-to-file-while-seeing-it-in-console-in-the-same-time)

Comment: @8bittree This post is 3 years older and has more views and votes than the other question. The other question should be closed as a duplicate instead.

Comment: @Excellll [Age is irrelevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55251/opinions-on-closing-an-older-question-as-a-duplicate-of-a-newer-question). I flagged this as the duplicate because I believe that the other has a [superior](http://superuser.com/a/694098/302463) answer.

Comment: There's an excellent overview of the available options in [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/731237/23900).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use `tee`.

```
user@unknown:~$ sudo command -option | tee log
```

Comment: Easy to remember if one thinks of the output being split by an upper case "T".  E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)#/media/File:Tee.svg

Comment: .. | tee -a log

To keep appending to the existing log. Otherwise every new line overwrites the log.

Answer (score 13):

The command you're looking for is 'tee' which makes a data connection similar to a pipe-tee.  it sends data two ways.
So

> sudo command -option | tee log

would tee the command output to both the file 'log' and to stdout, in this case, your terminal.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `script` [ http://linux.die.net/man/1/script ] to capture everything that occurs in your terminal session.

> Script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.  It is
>        useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an interactive session
>        as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out
>        later with lpr(1).