# copy (split?) stdout instead of redirecting it

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, redirection, stdout

In Bash, I'd like to redirect stdout to a file (>> mylog.txt) but also see the stdout output on the screen..

How can I do it with bash?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/159059/how-to-show-output-on-terminal-and-save-to-a-file-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `tee`:

```
command | tee -a mylog.txt
```

will append the output of the command to the file and also show it on screen.