# Command for printing output to console and file at same time on different threads

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, console

I am writing a bash script and would like the very last command to start as a separate process.   The last command also sends all output to a file. I also, however, want the output to still appear on the console. 
What I have so far is,

```
$ command > "file" &
```

This sends the output to "file" and also starts the command as its own process.
However, I also want to view the output in the console at the same time (but if I hit ctrl+c or w/e, the command doesnt stop). This is a lot like [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/694064/echoing-output-to-file-while-seeing-it-in-console-in-the-same-time), but with the caviat that it needs to be its own thread.

I have tried:

```
$ command | tee "file" &
```

but the problem is that tee is than part of the process, and output doesn't actually appear..

So, just to clarify, I want to have `command` on its own process, sending output to a file, but still have the output appear in the console (until I hit q, enter, ctrl+c, or something). Since this is in a bash script, two separate lines would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want `command` to finish writing to the file, but you want to be able to interrupt the display to the console. I would take a different approach to the solution. In your script:

```
> "file"
command > "file" &
tail -n +1 -F "file"
```

**Correction:**

The original answer used `-n 0`, which initially outputs no lines of `"file"` but outputs any lines added to `"file"` after `tail` is started. This was not my intention--it was a mistake. I intended to use an option that would list all lines of `"file"` even if `command` had written some before `tail` was started. The correct option for that behavior is `-n +1`.

From the `tail(1)` man page:

```
   -n, --lines=K   output the last K lines, instead of the last 10;
                   or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth
```

The first line clears the contents of the file in case of a race condition where `tail` hits the file before `command`.

Comment: Could you explain what the `-n 0` flag does?

Comment: Yes, the wrong thing! See my correction above. I'm glad you asked.

Comment: If the file doesn’t already exist, you might want to do something like `> file; command > file & tail -n +1 -F file` or `command > file & sleep 1; tail -n +1 -F file`, to protect against the race condition in which the `tail` process starts before the `file` is created. In the first option you might need to use `command >> file` or `command >| file` to allow writing to a file that already exists.

Comment: I think a better solution to the race condition is to just add `touch file` a line before `command`. However, in my case, the file will always exists.

Comment: Scratch that, a better solution is to echo nothing into the file. This clears the contents of the file before `tail` reads it.

Comment: Note that I deleted the echo command in favor of just `> "file"` which actually makes the file empty instead of writing a newline to it.