# How to pipe output of command to another command while also displaying it on the console?

Tags: command-line, bash, unix, pipe, stdout

I want to write part of the results of a stream to a file, but I want the entire contents of the stream printed to the console.  Is there some command that would help with this?

#### Minimal example:

Say I had a file `foo.txt` with contents:

```
bat
dude
rude
```

And I wanted to write all lines in that file which contain the letter 'a' to `bar.txt`. I could write

```
cat foo.txt | grep 'a' > bar.txt
```

Which would result in `bar.txt` containing `bat`. But that wouldn't give me the console output that I want.

Instead I would prefer something like:

```
cat foo.txt | output-stdin-to-console-and-pass-to-stdout | grep 'a' > bar.txt
```

Which would not only write `bat` to `bar.txt` but also write the following to the console:

```
bat
dude
rude
```

Is there any command I can run to do that?

Comment: [How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/418896/995714), [How can I both pipe and display output in Windows' command line?](https://superuser.com/q/767680/241386), [How to show output on terminal and save to a file at the same time?](https://superuser.com/q/159059/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit examples with `tee`:

- `tee` writing to the tty

  ```
  < foo.txt tee /dev/tty | grep 'a' > bar.txt
  ```

  This is portable, works in `sh`.
- `tee` writing to process substitution, its standard output goes to the console:

  ```
  < foo.txt tee >(grep 'a' > bar.txt)
  ```

  This is [not portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/309547/108618), works in Bash and few other shells.

Note I got rid of the `cat` command ([useless use of `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)).

Comment: I love this because its a chance for me to learn redirection better. Here's an comparison of two lines that makes it clear for me (`echo hello > file; echo world >> file`): `cat file | tee /dev/tty | grep hello` and `< file tee /dev/tty | grep hello` ..both output a tee of "hello" and "world", and then the piped the found line of "hello". Also `tee /dev/tty < file | grep hello` does the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use this:

`cat foo.txt && cat foo.txt | grep 'a' > bar.txt`

Otherwise, a one liner is possible using `tee`

From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tee-command-linux-example/

> tee command reads the standard input and writes it to both the standard
>   output and one or more files. The command is named after the
>   T-splitter used in plumbing. It basically breaks the output of a
>   program so that it can be both displayed and saved in a file. It does
>   both the tasks simultaneously, copies the result into the specified
>   files or variables and also display the result.